# What is the proper name for all the link, script, and meta tags in the head tag

Tags: php, html

So i'm using PHP to include all the link, script, and meta tags inside my head tag by using the following code:

```
<?php include(Config::get('file/html_headers')); ?>
```

Where it includes the following file:

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/headers/htmlHeaders.php'
```

Because i want to name this 'htmlHeaders' file to make sense to other programmers what should this file name be named? I'm confused as to what these tags are called categorically speaking. Are they html headers?

Heres the contents of htmlHeaders.php

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bootswatch.com/darkly/bootstrap.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript
     MUST BE LOADED AFTER jQuery -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Now Doing Some Cleaning Up -->
<!--
Fix Bootstrap's Grid Issues
Apply "flex" class to div with class = "row"
Example: <div class="row flex"><div class="col-lg-12"></div></div>
-->
<style type="text/css">
    .flex {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
</style>
<!-- Ensuring Proper Rendering & Touch Zooming on Mobile Devices -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Improving Cross-Browser Rendering -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/necolas/normalize.css/master/normalize.css">
```

Comment: I don't know if that's what you want to hear, but you just call that the 'head' (as the tag suggests)

Comment: I don't think there's any generic name for them, it's just called the `<head>` of them, and the elements are tags like anything else in HTML.

Comment: I call it `resources`

Comment: building on what Muhammad Ibnuh said, perhaps name the file htmlHeadResources , that should be enough to gauge its contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3School calls them "head elements" as they are elements that appear in the `<head>` tag. The W3C HTML spec says it is "data that is not considered document content" which you could simply shorten to "non-document content".  I usually simply call that file `__headContents.<ext>` or just `__head.<ext>`, personally.

I would say in regard to the other answers and comments however:

1. They are not "headers."  In HTTP, headers are the things sent prior to the HTML, like cookies, ETags, and so on -- that word means something specific in HTTP.  If you call them headers, at some point you'll regret it due to the confusion it will cause.
2. They are not "assets."  Assets means "additional external files" and covers things like CSS & external JS as well as images; meta & title tags for example are not assets, and assets can be referenced outside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I chose to name the file headContents.php!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and CSS type of things are called "assets."

If you're including PHP code, then that's just a header on a web site.  From your code, it looks like PHP script creates the HTML to include the assets.

Answer (score 0):

What about *document meta*? In essence, anything in the `<head>` describes the current document, hence meta.

Also, in SEO land, one would call the content of the `<head>` meta tags.